# Save mongoose parent model with embedded sub documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

These are my schema

```
    // in test schema file
    const Test = new mongoose.Schema(
      {
        _id: { type: String, default: uuid.v1 },
        responses: [Response]
      },
      {
        timestamps: true
      }
    );


    // in response schema file 
    const Response = new mongoose.Schema({
      _id: { type: String, default: uuid.v1 },
      answer: {
        type: String,
        enum: [
          "StronglyAgree",
          "Agree",
          "SomewhatAgree",
          "Neutral",
          "SomewhatDisagree",
          "Disagree",
          "StronglyDisagree"
        ]
      },
      question: { type: String, ref: "Question" }
    });
```

I try and enter in responses to my test like so

```
  async create() {
    try {
      const test = new this.model({ _id: uuid.v1() });
      const questions = await this.questionModel.getAllQuestions();

      questions.forEach(question => {
        test.responses.push({
          question: question._id,
          answer: "StronglyAgree"
        });
      });
      var savedTest = await test.save();
      savedTest = await this.model.populate(test, {
        path: "responses.question"
      });

      return savedTest;
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

I get this error

```
 { responses: 
      MongooseError {
        message: 'Cast to Array failed for value "1" at path "responses"',
        name: 'CastError',
        stringValue: '"1"',
        kind: 'Array',
        value: 1,
        path: 'responses',
        reason: [Object] } },
  _message: 'Test validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: this script should throw `ReferenceError: Response is not defined`

Comment: `.push()` is not `async`. Nothing here actually is until your call `.save()` Also `test.responses = test.responses.push` should simply be `test.responses.push`, since you are getting the error because it's an "assignment" where you do not need it. `.push()` also does not "return" a value. It mutates the existing content instead.

Comment: @Adam the schema are in different files, I just pasted them together for convenience.

Comment: @NeilLunn changed - but those don't explain the error.

Comment: Yes it does. `test.responses =  ` That's the error. You don't "assign".

Comment: so this now gives me a maximum call stack exceeded error. The number of questions is 2.

Comment: `.populate()` **is** async. You forgot the `await` there. Honestly there are more problems really. If this is supposed to be a static method on a schema then it really should be returning a promise and not plain values. This is all easily resolved by looking at the manual.

Comment: Yup - changed that. Still a max call stack size exceeded error.

Comment: Do you understand the concept of **one question**??? You don't ask a question here and then get to to say. "Oh now this problem." and "Oh another problem"

Comment: Point taken - do you want to put your thing as an answer, so that I can accept it?